# How do I get my values out of their SimpleXMLObjects?

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

After an xPath, I'm left with this var_dump:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "22-99586795"
  }
}
```

echoing the damn thing only gives me "Array()"

How do I get the bloody string out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting it to string

```
print (string)$yourarray[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an array with one item, so you need to do:

```
$myelement[0];
```

or

```
$myelement[0][0];
```

(I can't tell from your question which element you're referring to)

Comment: `var_dump($newXML->xpath("//ID")[0]);` Has been tried to no avail

Comment: `$id = implode("", $newXML->xpath("//ID"));` worked, but is a method so dirty really necessary to fetch data in one line? (My goal is to get ID from XML in **one** line of code)

Comment: You can't use array subscripts on return values in PHP - you have to assign the return value to a variable and subscript that.